# ng-click and ng-model in AngularJs 1.2 and Angular 1.4

Tags: angularjs

I came across a scenario while upgrading from AngularJS 1.2 to 1.4.

I have a check box with ng-click and ng-model directive.
I am using model inside ng-click.

```
$scope.clickEvent = function(){
    $log($scope.myModel);
}
```

In AngularJS 1.2 the output was

```
old value of the controller
```

In AngularJS 1.4 the output was

```
New value of the controller.
```

I was looking into the breaking changes log while upgrading from 1.2 to 1.4.

So the question is:
Was it a bug in AngularJS 1.2 or was a feature which later modified in AngularJS 1.4?
If this was a feature in AngularJS 1.2 then what's the motivation behind changing this behaviour?

Reference Link:
[Issue Reported in AngularJS 1.2 which was justified as behavior](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4765)

Answer (score 0):

After looking through angularJS documentation and some example I found that in v1.2 it was the default behavior because of the order of execution/priority of both the directives.
[V1.2 Discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4765)

And in V1.3/1.4 its the opposite. First model is being updated and click event is fired.

There is another way to work with this. Instead of using the model property try using $event.target.value because it contains updated value.